# How I can add laser to my diff drive robot in gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, laser, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I am beginner in gazebo and ROS. I am trying to implement global path planner to get data from laser. For that purpose I need to know which laser sensor or sonar can help in this task. How I can integrate laser or sonar to my diff drive robot?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246371/how-i-can-add-laser-to-my-diff-drive-robot-in-gazebo?/) by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would help you install a laser sensor in your Gazebo model.
[Gazebo Tutorial: Adding a Laser](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=add_laser)

This would only let you mount this device. For controlling it, you would need ROS nodes.
You can also control it using Gazebo Plugins.

---

Originally posted by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) with karma: 123 on 2016-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on 2016-10-25**:
Thanks for your answer. I will try it

**Comment by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on 2016-10-26**:
I have tried it and it's working. Thanks